# What is the meaning of "Hit me with the quick fix?

Tags: nouns

What does the sentence mean " hit me with the quick fix, John "

Answer (score 3):

The colloquial [*Hit me with it!*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hit-with) (meaning *Give it to me*) is more commonly used where "it" is some unpleasant or surprising information, but OP's cited usage isn't uncommon.

A [*quick fix*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quick+fix) (also colloquial, but nowhere near as "slangy" as *Hit me...*) simply means *an easy and quick repair or remedy*.

A common equivalent today (that only really works in the written form) is [Gimme teh codez](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question) (Don't bother explaining how I should solve my programming problem - just give me some code I can use without thinking).